# How to use other field value using java (Spring) mongodb update and push?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

Before update:

```
{
  id:...,
  field1: v1,
  field2: [v2,v3]
}
```

v* are instances of class V

After update:

```
{
  id:...,
  field1: new_v,
  field2: [v1,v2,v3]
}
```

Tried the following:

```
Query select = Query.query(Criteria.where(id).in(docIdList));
Update update = new Update();
update.push("field2").atPosition(0).value("$field1");
V new_v = new V("NEW");
update.set("field1",new_v);
UpdateResult updateResult = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(select, update,V.class);
```

The problem is that I am getting:

```
{
  id:...,
  field1: new_v,
  field2: [field1,v2,v3]
}
```